# Which issue of which Spider-Man series had Spidey fighting a villain in a white costume with black spots?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man

I remember reading an issue of *a* Spider-Man series that had Spidey fighting a villain in a white costume with black spots. The spots were actually a kind of portal, which meant that the villain couldn't be hit there. He could also detach the portals and throw them at Spider-Man, then punch through another portal to have his fist come out from the portal near Spider-Man's head and hit him. He was defeated after picking too many portals from his costume, which meant that Spidey had more surface to hit the villain.

I read this in Dutch in the early '80s, but it was at the barber, so it may have been an older issue — he had a stack.

Does anyone know which issue this was (either English original or Dutch translation)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> He was defeated after picking too many portals from his costume, which meant that Spidey had more surface to hit the villain.

Judging by this part of your description in particular, it sounds like you're thinking of ***[Spectacular Spider-Man Vol. 1 #100](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_100)*** (March, 1985), which featured Spider-Man's second battle with the villain, [Spot](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Johnathon_Ohnn_(Earth-616)). They had their first fight in [the previous issue](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_99).

[image]

Comment: I wish the MCU had comic-book-style dialog like this. Imagine how much better the _Winter Soldier_ elevator fight would have been with Chris Evans narrating every move he makes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Heh, rather "how much campier" it would have been. While it would probably make me chuckle, I'm quite glad the directors and producers of the MCU films take them *seriously*.

Comment: @TylerH I mean, *ish*. America's ass, and all that.